# 400 Bad Request Invalid verb - when trying to update field value with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, http-400-bad-request

I am trying to update a field value in a SharePoint document library through SharePoint REST API. I am successfully when I try using Fiddler. When I send a command through Java code, it gives 400 Bad Request. Appreciate any help.

Document Library:
[image]

Success when trying with Fiddler:
[image: Fiddler Success]

Wireshark capture (Failure with Java Code):

[image: Wireshark Capture - failure]